# how can i access json object in javascript and convert it into array in java?

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, dom

In controller class, I am sending one json object (data) how can i access it in javascript? and i want it to be converted into array containing object

```
 @RequestMapping("/piechart")
public String getChartDetails(Map<String, Object> model) throws                   Exception{
    List<ChartEntry> chartEntries =chartService.getChartEntryCounts();
    ChartData data = new ChartData();
    data.setChartEntry(chartEntries);
    model.put("data", Resources.objectAsJson(data));

    return "/analyticsChart";
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript. If you have data in JSON format, you'll need to parse it in your Java app.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming you are using JSP for view part.

*There is one possibility 
You can assign your model object to a javascript variable as*

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
var response = ${data};
</script>
```

Now you can use this Javascript response object as your wish.